# Set trigger to create an auto increment field

Tags: sql-server, triggers

My situation: I have a MS CRM 3.0 install that uses MSSQL 2000 SP4 - there are no options for creating auto increment fields inside the entity creation tool.  After research I have concluded to do this you need to 1.) use the crm sdk 2.) create a trigger.  Currently I do not have the time / means to mess with the sdk so I'm trying to set up a trigger.

I have navigated to MS Enterprise Manager found the table I want to modify, right clicked and selected Manage Triggers.  I have also created the INT field via my CRM admin area and queried the DB to set a value for my "AccountNumber" to 10001 (this way my trigger doesn't have to deal with a null value and can grab this 10001 and + 1 it).

I have tried some code but am unfamiliar with the syntax and the way to grab the previously entered accountnumber and then incrementing it for the record being inserted.  (I assume there is an "AFTER INSERT" function?)

Some code examples would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: MSSQL can do that for you without a trigger. Just define an int/bigint field with `IDENTITY(x,y)` where x is the initial number (10000) and y is the increment (1): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Marc B - OK I did this - tested it and it works as desired.  But theres one big problem, I cannot access this field from my CRM customization area to add to views and forms (when I go there its not listed as an option (I guess because it was created through sql directly and not the CRM attribute interface)).  So my question is can I add the IDENTITY property to an INT field that is already created?

Comment: I don't think Marc B's suggestion will work with my set up (MS CRM) - Any please advise on my original question!  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind!  Tried answering the question but SO won't let me yet.  Marc B if you put that into an answer I will accept.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL can do that for you without a trigger. Just define an int/bigint field with IDENTITY(x,y) where x is the initial number (10000) and y is the increment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: One thing to note: if you are in the same situation I was (w/ CRM 3.0) you have to trick it into thinking it created the field.  So 1.) create the field in crm 2.) alter table and drop the field and in the same statement alter the table and add it (with the same name) with the IDENTITY option.